# No shape in pretrained Keras Inception vs demanded shapes after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to perform feature visualization with the Lucid Toolkit(https://github.com/tensorflow/lucid) using the Keras InceptionV3().

When I inspect the shapes of the layers inside the network after  I trained it, they are of a given shape:

```
================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 300, 400, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 149, 199, 32) 864         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 149, 199, 32) 96          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 149, 199, 32) 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 147, 197, 32) 9216        activation_1[0][0]
```

...

In contrast ,the model with pretrained imageNet-weights doesnt have such restrictions:

```
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, None, None, 3 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 864         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 96          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 3 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 9216        activation_1[0][0]
```

So, the problem is, that when I want to perform visualization, with the pretrained Net it works, with mine however, not.

Does anyone know, why there are no constraints for the shapes of the layers, because there should be, at least for the number of filters in each conv-layer.

Thanks for any help,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the images doesn't affect convolutional models in any way regarding weights. (It would cause problems with Flatten layers, for instance). Of course, the number of filters must be unchanged, otherwise you would indeed have a change in weights.

Filters are "image layers", not "image sizes". Small images produce small filtered layers, big images produce big filtered layers.

To create a Keras Inception model for variable image sizes, you must define the input shape as `(None, None, 3)`.

```
inceptionModel = keras.applications.inception_v3(...,input_shape=(None,None,3),....)
```

You can use the weights from your trained model (if you trained it somehow) by transfering:

```
inceptionModel.set_weights(trainedModel.get_weights())
```

Comment: Tank you, 

this actually worked for me. 
Yes, thats what i meant. At least 3, the channelsize, has to be defined, otherwise it wouldnt be defined how many filters, each with shared weights, have to be in each layer.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to comment about the filters :)